# Angular: Drag and drop for trees - customisation

Tags: angular, angular-material

To my understanding the new Angular 7 provides Drag and Drop features. I searched for the Tree component about the DnD but didn't find much related to trees.

One working expample I've found on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draggable-mat-tree). Compared with the drag'ndrop features summarized [here](https://grokonez.com/frontend/angular/angular-7/angular-7-drag-and-drop-example-angular-material-cdk) the solution looks sober. One better sample is related with [ngx-tree-dnd](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-tree-dnd?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts). Nevertheless since I want to stick to Material some q arise:

1. How to make the *regular* Angular tree have some similar ghosting effects? i.e. Display the node content while dragging around.
2. Is there a way to visually display it better if I drop the node on the same level or one deeper/upper? Cuz with the current display it is hardly recognizable onto which level the moved
3. How to include some animations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some investigation of the code and fumbling around I figured finally out how to make it better. I post my solution on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draggable-mat-tree-cu2tmi) in case somebody else wanna make additional adjustments.

Major issues I've fixed:

1. The image for dropping was set to null - no idea why
2. I increased the drag and drop area - so it covers now as well the margins (paddings)
3. I color the node where the selection starts
4. Adjustements about the colors could be easily done in the CSS
5. I tried to fix perfomance issue. One approach is to use numbers instead of string. But I guess there could be additional improvements.

I figured out that the major thing about DnD is that most of the part is plain JS code. Not much spiced up with Angular specifics.

Suggestions about improvements welcome.